# AWS Amplify - Graphql + Datastore: Variable 'input' has coerced Null value for NonNull type String

Tags: reactjs, graphql, aws-amplify

Running into a problem with the API generated with aws amplify.

Basically, I keep getting the following warning whenever I try to create one entity and it is not being persisted in DynamoDB.

`Variable 'input' has coerced Null value for NonNull type 'String!`

The following are the pertinent parts of the Graphql schema I used to create the backend.

```
enum EntityStatus {
     ACTIVE
     INACTIVE
     ARCHIVED
    }

type Address {
  streetAddress1: String!
  streetAddress2: String
  city: String!
  state: String!
  zipCode: String!
  country: String!
  location: Location!
}

type Location {
  lat: Float
  lng: Float
}

type Tenant
  @model
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: groups, groups: ["Admin", "Coordinator", "Employees"], operations }
      { allow: groups, groups: ["Auditor"], operations: [read] }
    ]
  ) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  address: Address!
  phone: AWSPhone!
  email: AWSEmail!
  status: EntityStatus!
  locale: String!
}
```

The code to create one of the `Tenant` entities is a simple call

```js
    try {
      return await DataStore.save(new Tenant({ ...values }));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
```

The payload going sent by Datastore is as follows:

```json
{
  "name": "Tenant 1",
  "phone": "1234567890",
  "email": "tenant@tenant.com",
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "address": {
    "city": "Anytown",
    "state": "TAB",
    "zipCode": "12345",
    "country": "US",
    "location": { "lat": 123.12, "lng": 123.12 }
  },
  "locale": "en-US",
  "id": "f8be53bd-b1cb-4cbd-9b64-01fdf930da8a"
}
```

Here is the full Warning message

```
[WARN] 40:26.787 DataStore 
Object { localModel: {…}, message: "Variable 'input' has coerced Null value for NonNull type 'String!'", operation: "Create", errorType: undefined, errorInfo: undefined, remoteModel: null }
errorInfo: undefined
errorType: undefined
localModel: Object { id: "f8be53bd-b1cb-4cbd-9b64-01fdf930da8a", name: "Tenant 1", phone: "1234567890", … }
_deleted: undefined
_lastChangedAt: undefined
_version: undefined
address: Object { city: "Anytown", state: "TAB", zipCode: "12345", … }
createdAt: undefined
email: "tenant@tenant.com"
id: "f8be53bd-b1cb-4cbd-9b64-01fdf930da8a"
locale: "en-US"
name: "Tenant 1"
phone: "1234567890"
status: "ACTIVE"
updatedAt: undefined
<prototype>: Object { … }
message: "Variable 'input' has coerced Null value for NonNull type 'String!'"
operation: "Create"
remoteModel: null
<prototype>: Object { … }
react_devtools_backend.js:3973:25
```

Comment: The interesting bit is that I get a Warn not an error and Datastore claims to have completed


```Mutation sent successfully with authMode: AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. My payload was missing 2 fields.

Wish that the error messages would be more helpful.